# nodejs newbie, how can I know with which version of nodejs does the couchbase library is compatible with?

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I'm looking at [couchbase library for nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/couchbase) how can I know with which version of `nodejs` is this library compatible with? does it match node version `4.4.4`? is there a way to see different versions of this `couchbase` library and see one that suits `node 0.12.x.` and one which suits node version `4.4.4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no official way of working this out unless it is explicitly mentioned in a file in the repository (most often the README.md).

For a lot of the larger modules however, there is an alternative, you can install the latest version with:

`npm install <module>`

Navigate to that module and run:

`npm test`

To make sure that the version is compatible with your current version.  If there are errors, look to see if you can fix them, if they seem to be compatibility issues, simply downgrade the installation. E.G:

`npm uninstall <package>
npm install <package>@1.5.0`